# Servicestack How to get the jsonserviceclient to work with custom authentication

Tags: servicestack

Looking at the ServiceStack.UseCases example project. I am trying to use the jsonserviceclient to call the HelloRequest service after I have called the authentication service. No matter what I do it appears to be failing and returning the Not Found error message. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/api";
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
        client.UserName = "admin";
        client.Password = "123";
        client.SetCredentials("admin", "123");
        client.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;
        client.Send(new HelloRequest { Name = "Mike" });
    }
```

The server has the service configured like

```
 public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Custom Authentication Example", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        // register storage for user sessions 
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        // Register AuthFeature with custom user session and custom auth provider
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new CustomUserSession(), 
            new[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }
        ));
    }
}
```

What I would really like is a good solution to the following problem I have. I have an existing system with an existing user database and custom authentication process. I am now trying to expose the functions of the system as web services using servicestack. I program using bog standard webforms so the MVC examples dont work too well for me. I am just looking for the best solution for my particular scenario where I can authenticate callers to my webservice with the majority of my clients using webforms in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to have Basic Auth enabled on the server you're trying to authenticate with. 
See the [SocialBootstrapApi AppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/AppHost.cs#L171) for an example:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new CustomUserSession(), //Use your own typed Custom UserSession type
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new BasicAuthProvider(),                    //Sign-in with Basic Auth
    }));
```

Comment: Th example is using CustomCredentialsAuthProvider which is a class that extends the CredentialsAuthProvider. Are you saying I need to get rid of that and use the BasicAuthProvider instead?

Comment: Yes, It needs to inherit from BasicAuthProvider instead.

Comment: Seems to crash out completely now. Getting the error message Internal server error.

Comment: That's a generic ASP.NET error message for any error, you need to find out what the underlying exception is and resolve it from there.

Comment: Hi Mythz, do you have any suggestion regarding my particular scenario. I have an existing web applicaton. I intend to use servicestack to expose the features in my db. I want to authenticate service callers against my existing DB. Primary choice of client is webforms using the jsonserviceclient.

Comment: If ServiceStack is in the same ASP.NET Web Application I wouldn't be using any JsonServiceClient, just call the AuthService directly with `AppHostBase.ResolveService<AuthService>()` similar to what's been done on [ServiceStack.UseCases](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L50)

Comment: THe client is not in the same web application. What would you now recommend :)

Comment: Sure you should use a remote service client when it's remote.